# Professional / formal version of "sitting pretty"

Tags: phrase-requests

Consider the sentence:

> This leaves Plan A *sitting pretty* and remains the only option that
>   keeps Goal A firmly on the table.

In my formal document, I cannot have an idiom like "sitting pretty" since it's very casual. However, it's challenging to think of alternatives.

### Question

Is there a more formal/professional word or phrase I could use in place of "sitting pretty" in the above sentence?

- Best I could do: "more desirable"

Comment: Well, in the Brexit No Deal débacle, the phrase is “the default option”.

Comment: I’d call plan A the only viable option and thus the preferred option to consider, the most promising approach, the one that should be the focus of further development efforts, etc, etc,

Comment: @Tuffy 'backstop' is bandied about

Comment: @marcellothearcane Indeed it is, but that is intended by its defenders as a ‘safety net’ or ‘insurance policy’ (to prevent the possibility of a resumption of armed conflict returning to Northern Ireland.  At present, it is neither a default option nor ‘sitting pretty’!  Default option happen in the event that no alternative can be agreed.  In the Brexit case, unless parliament can find a majority for an alternative and agree it with the EU, UK leaves the EU without a deal on 31Oct19.  That ‘default option’ is thus ‘sitting pretty’.

Comment: What exactly do you want to convey by "sitting pretty"? It does not mean "more desirable" at all. Can you explain?

Comment: confining any answer to the Brexit context is difficult.

Comment: I would say it's not idiomatic to talk about a _plan_ as 'sitting pretty'; it's usually used of a human referent. '... as favourite' is probably an idiom, certainly idiomatic, usable with a non-human referent, cross-register, and what I'd use.

Comment: I'd say "well-positioned" if I were trying to be more formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Collins dictionary's definition of [**be sitting pretty**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-sitting-pretty):

> If you are **sitting pretty**, you are in a very favourable situation.
> *[informal]
>
> If we'd let them buy it for a quarter of a million, we'd be sitting pretty by now.*

---

Alternatives to *sitting pretty* (and the sentence) are then as follows:

> This leaves Plan A *in a good position*, and [it] remains the only option that keeps Goal A firmly on the table.
>
> This leaves Plan A *in good shape*, and [it] remains the only option that keeps Goal A firmly on the table.
>
> This leaves Plan A *doing well*, and the only option that keeps Goal A firmly on the table.
>
> This leaves Plan A *well positioned* to keep Goal A firmly on the table.

Answer (score 1):

**pretty**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pretty) adv

> fairly, rather, quite, kind of (informal), somewhat, moderately,
>   **reasonably**

Thus, my sense points to **reasonable** as a non-idiomatic and more formal alternative in any context:

As in:

This leave X **reasonable** and ...